# how do I create multiple VMs from the same OS image with the same rendering output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, virtual-machines, graphical-user-interface

Currently I am doing pixel v pixel on a single AWS VM.

I am running all test on a single machine comparing golden vs test image.

Id like to do pixel v pixel tests on multiple machines to parallelize testing using a single master golden image db.

Does anyone know if I create multiple VMs from the same OS image would their rendering output look the same?

how will i use this: I want to compare 2 of the same images from generated from different VMs and their pixel v pixel should be same.

Also can't guarantee that the underlying hardware on those vms is the same.

Ignore Performance testing and not doing graphics pass through

Comment: Whether the output will be the same is really a question about the software, best guess is it probably will be with the same input and same software. It's trivial to create multiple VMs from the same image (AMI) to test this.

Comment: Surely technology is sufficiently advanced that the algorithm used to generate or render the image runs consistently on different machines... The movie industry can't render IMAX movies on a single machine else it'd take decades... I'm curious what problem you're trying to solve!